# Excel formula to count duplicates as one

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am trying to create a formula which will count all rows (duplicates as one) based on a value in another column.

| Column A | Column B. |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | Joe Bloggs |
| p2 | Bob Bloggs |
| p1 | Joe Bloggs |
| p3 | John Bloggs |
| p1 | Mary Bloggs |
| p1 | Alan Bloggs |

I want to count the number of rows where the value in column A === p1. So on the above running

`=COUNTIF(A1:A20,"p1")` will return 4, but as Joe Bloggs is p1 twice I only want to count Joe Bloggs once.

Running `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B15<>"")/COUNTIF(B1:B15,B1:B15&""))` will count duplicates as one, this would return 5 people as it would only count Joe Bloggs once.

Is it possible to combine the `COUNTIF` and `SUMPRODUCT`.

Something else I tried was adding this forumla in Column C, `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A3,A3,B$1:B3,B3)>1, COUNTIFS(A$1:A3,A3,B$1:B3,B3)-1,"")` this would count the duplicates and then I can run `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A20,"p1")-COUNTIF(Sheet1!C1:C7,">0")` but if `p2` or `p3` had duplicates then this would not generate the correct result.

So basically I am trying to say, `IF Column A is p1 then count all p1 rows but IF column B has duplicates then only count the first instance (counting the duplicates as 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array formula:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10=E2,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0)),ROW(B2:B10)-1)>0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Adding extra rows will sometimes give the result as decimal, therefore I formatted that cell to remove decimal and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @BernardBonjoThompson yeah, you are right, my mistake. Rewrote the answer with correct formula.

Comment: Hey @basic is it possible to expand this array if we sepreate the first and last night and generate the same result based on this, three columns A,B,C. A being the p1s, Column B, first name and Column C last name

Comment: @BernardBonjoThompson If I understood correctly, it will be enough to concatenate ranges, i.e. ```=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10=E2,MATCH(B2:B10&C2:C10,B2:B10&C2:C10,0)),ROW(B2:B10)-1)>0))```

Comment: Ah perfect, all I need to do is add the "AND" makes sense, thank you